# Replacing string with PHP code

Tags: php

I am trying to replace a certain string with some PHP code using the `str_replace` function. I want to replace `"[GOOGLE]"` with `<?php echo "hello"; ?>`

Here's what I have so far:

```
$text = str_replace("[GOOGLE]", "<?php echo 'hello'; ?>", $text);
```

When running this code, it does replace `[GOOGLE]`, but the replacement is not shown in the browser. When I go to see the page's source code, the replacement is: `<?php echo 'hello'; ?>` you can see the PHP tag for some reason. However, nothing is displayed on the page. How do I correct this problem so that `[GOOGLE]` is replaced with hello? Note: I do not want to replace my PHP code in the `str_replace` function with the actual "hello" string, I want to do this with PHP code. For now, I am trying to go with something simple. My goal is to replace `[GOOGLE]` with an if/else statement and Ad code for my CMS.

Comment: why not just `hello`

Comment: ^ if I could upvote that 50 times, I would. But then they'd probably call me "trigger happy" and I'd be out of votes.

Comment: ^ that was meant for you @Ghost lol I guess you knew that ;-)

Comment: *"Note: I do not want to replace my PHP code in the str_replace function with the actual "hello" string"* That is like you want to walk a meter without walking. Just use `hello` as a replacement, like everyone else would do it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- start off the year in PHP tag with headscratcher questions

Comment: @Ghost *"start off the year in PHP"* - I guess that the word "right" was appropriately left out ;-) *Happy New Year btw* <cheers>

Comment: When you do `str_replace` and replace with PHP code inside PHP tags, that PHP code does not get evaluated. You would have to use something like [eval](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) (Don't use eval). So instead you get a literal `<?php ... ?>` which your browser just thinks is a long HTML element because it is within angle brackets. Therefore it doesn't even show that output in your browser (unless you view source). Bottom line, just use `hello` as Ghost said.

Comment: what are you going to do with `$text` that you need it to contain php code?

Comment: @Ghost I do not wish to replace [GOOGLE] with hello, I am just starting off with something simple for now to know how to do the complicated stuff. For example, I want to replace [GOOGLE] with Adsense code in my CMS.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm starting off with something simple for right now to learn how to do it. I want to really replace [GOOGLE] with Adsense code to use in my CMS

Comment: @user2896120 that adsense code is just a simple html markup, create the whole markup string in the PHP (add your data and whatnot), then make the replacement using that `str_replace`, you're already in your PHP script making the processes, do it there already

Comment: @Ghost Well I could, but I want to run an if/else statement before showing the Ad code to check if some variables exist. If they don't exist, then the ad should not show up. You gave me an idea though to make it more simple. I will run the if/else statement outside the replace function.

Comment: Look at the source code, you should see it, the browser will think `<?php echo 'hello'; ?>` ( literal ) is an HTML tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `echo` appears misplaced. It seems to me you want to output the result of replacing "[GOOGLE]" with "hello", in which case (1) perform the replacement then (2) echo the result. Perhaps:

```
$text = str_replace("[GOOGLE]", "hello", $text);
echo $text;
```

The reason you don't see it in the browser is that replacement, `<?php echo 'hello'; >` is within angled brackets. Angled brackets are special to HTML, in that they denote an operation the browser is to perform. For example, `<b>` means "start bolding text". When the browser sees "<?php ... ?>" it considers that a tag. It doesn't know what to do with the tag, so nothing appears rendered. However, it does remain in source as that text is, indeed, part of the source.

If you literaly want to see `"<?php echo 'hello'; ?>"` then you need to escape the angled brackets:

```
$text = str_replace("[GOOGLE]", "&lt;?php echo 'hello'; ?&gt;", $text);
```

Here the angled brackets have been replaced with their escaped versions: "<" becomes "&lt;" and ">" becomes "&gt;". Of course, you might tire of doing this manually. In which case, consider using [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Comment: I want to see the result of <?php echo 'hello'; ?> and not the tags. I want to see the word hello

Comment: Good and thoughtful description on this answer, it also addresses both cases, should they want the literal PHP or the result.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to display php code on html page.
You need to use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) for that because this string will be partly interpreted as html tag.

In your example it would be:

```
$text = str_replace("[GOOGLE]", "<?php echo 'hello'; ?>", $text);
// later when producing html...
echo htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES); //default encoding is UTF-8
```

**WARNING:** It's mandatory to do it with every user supplied content btw, because javascript could be also interpreted and someone could do nasty things with it (XSS)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm starting off with something simple for right now to learn how to do it. I want to really replace [GOOGLE] with Adsense code to use in my CMS

Don't do it this way.

Put your Adsense code in an include or a variable or something, and do:

```
$text = str_replace("[GOOGLE]", file_get_contents('google-analytics.html'), $text);
```

or:

```
$googleAnalytics = '<script> the code Google gives you </script>';
$text = str_replace("[GOOGLE]", $googleAnalytics, $text);
```